# How can I compare all the values of an enum with a given array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I have an enum class with values:

```
  enum carBrand{BMW,HONDA,MERC,AUDI};
```

And there's an array called Sales with Array values:

```
 sales[] = {CHEVVY, BMW , MERC, AUDI};
```

So how could I check that the sales[] has all the values of enum carBrand?

I'm trying to put it in a for loop as:

```
 for(int i = 0; i<sales.length;i++){
     if(carBrand.sales == sales[i]){
        return true;
     }
 return false;
 }
```

Comment: One possibility: create a *set* from sales, *remove all* *values* of `CarBrands`, check if remaining set is empty (and starting set size is 4). Another possibility is an EnumMap with boolean values, iterate over sales, set the boolean to true for current key and after the loop check that there's no false in the enumMap.

Answer (score 0):

- Add carBrand values to list
- loop sales, remove the carBrand from the list
- check if list is empty, if so they have all the values

Note: Class names should be names in PascalCase (CarBrand, Sales)

Answer (score 0):

I would, personally, suggest using a list object rather than an Array where you are using such, however, this should work.

```
public static boolean checkArray(carBrand[] array) {
    for (carBrand c : carBrand.values()) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (carBrand a : array) {
            if (a == c) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

where the "array" parameter would be invoked as the `sales` object in your code.

This code will return false if not every enum value exists within your array.

Off-topic:
Things like this are actually all over the internet - here, google, even Bing (as garbo as Bing is), so searching before requesting help, probably a viable choice

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Enumeration {

    enum carBrand{BMW,HONDA,MERC,AUDI};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sales[] = {"CHEVVY", "BMW" , "MERC", "AUDI"};


        for(carBrand brand:carBrand.values()) {
            boolean bran=false;
            for(int i=0;i<sales.length;i++) {
                if(brand.toString()==sales[i]) {
                    bran=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!bran==true) {
                System.out.println("Sales doesn't have " +brand);
            }
        }

    }
}
```